# How to mixing between TailwindCSS and Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

Who can give me answer whether to mixing TailwindCSS with Chakra UI in ReactJS? Does it have conflicts between style classes name?

Answer (score 2):

You can append a custom prefix to all tailwind class names to avoid potential class name conflicts.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

[documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix)